# Github Pages and GitLab pages like functionality of hosting a Static Website in TFS / Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to have the functionality of creating a static website in TFS / Azure DevOps Server similar to that available in Github Pages and GitLab pages ?
Links:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_from_scratch.html
https://pages.github.com/

Comment: The closest thing is [Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/?view=azure-devops), but I doubt it is there to cover Github Pages idea.

Answer (score 11):

As the comment by Yan mentions, closest you can get is Wiki, but its not meant for that, it requires auth to use it.

There is no such feature in Azure DevOps, I'm afraid.

This issue exists: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16908766-support-for-static-doc-hosting-similar-compatible

Comment: Issue was moved. It is now here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365602/support-for-static-doc-hosting-similarcompatible-t.html

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how broad you make your definition of Azure DevOps. On Azure, it's easy to host a static content website and it's possible to link an Azure Website to a Git Repository in Azure DevOps. You can even serve a website straight from Blob Storage.

Or you can set up an Azure Pipeline to package, optionally transform and publish the content using Jekyll or Hugo.

It's not as simple as GitHub Pages, but ultimately, once set up, just as simple and eventually more powerful depending on what you want to achieve.

For publishing project documentation, you can also use [Public Projects and allow guest access to the Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/view-wiki-public?view=azure-devops).