# How do you create a git page on azure devops repo?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure DevOps, I have always used GitHub and BitBucket in my previous companies and in my personal life. In GitHub and BitBucket there is a very easy process to publish a static "GitHub Page" by - more or less - adding an index.html file and navigating to your github/bitbucket repo static page. Is there a way to do this using ADO?

I found this guide: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestaticwebapps but it says I need to connect to a GitHub account, I want to be able to do it from my Azure Repo. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you need something like a readme page ? it is available at the project level. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops

Comment: Also, please take a look at this thread and see if it helps -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756594/github-pages-and-gitlab-pages-like-functionality-in-tfs-azure-devops-server